# Telerik RadGridView check if Cell is in edit mode

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I want to show the user an info when he clicks on a cell in RadGridView, but only if the cell is not in editmode.
I use the CellClick event for this, but how can I determine if the cell is in edit mode or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need CellBeginEdit – Fires when the cell is about to enter edit mode. You can cancel edit mode at this stage by  setting the Cancel property to false.

```
  private void radGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, GridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "CustomColumn")
        {
           //do something
        }
    }
```